# update login status if cookie is deleted by force

Tags: php, cookies

I have this problem which keeps me from pushing towards my login page. I know that when you log in you can create a security by means of cookies and session and so i did. But using this EditThisCookie add on in google chrome, if i delete my cookies then I must update my database status to inactive. But im stucked on how to do it. Can some one help me regarding this problem. My code below.

```
$user  = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$sesskey   = $_SESSION['sesskey'];
$firstname   = $_SESSION['firstname'];

if(count($_COOKIE) > 0) {

} else {
$sqlupses   = "UPDATE credentials set loginkey = '', access_status  = 'inactive' where user_id = '$user'";
die($sqlupses);
$ressess    = mysql_query( $sqlupses, $dbhandle );
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('location:index.php?lvs=8');
exit();
}
```

Comment: When you edit or delete the cookie, there will be no connected session so you will not be able to get the user to update.

Comment: Is there any work around on that part?

Comment: Unless you use javascript and send the cookie status back to server in some intervals, there's no way for the server to know the cookie has been deleted. The session will only garbage collected.

Comment: Not really, you can only update a database field whenever a user does something and use a task scheduler to mark all users inactive that have no updated record for the last xx minutes / hours.